# Property 'connect' does not exist on type 'typeof import

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have problem when I try to use mongodb.connect() func..

```
import mongodb from "mongodb"
import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config()
mongodb.connect()
```

Then error appears " Property 'connect' does not exist on type 'typeof import(..)

Comment: are you using moongose or only mongodb?

Comment: @Eduardo mongodb only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connect functions exits inside mongoose package.

Look into this link for more info [https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose]

Answer (score 1):

To create a connection to mongodb, you should first import the MongoClient, then you need to create a instance of the client, and only through the instance you will be able to create the connection.

See the example bellow taken from mongodb package documentation in npm

```
  import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'


  const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
  const client = new MongoClient(url);
  await client.connect();
```

Check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) out for more details.